# InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream is not implementing InputStreamStatistics

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am try to automate testing using selenium from eclipse IDE but unfortunately stuck at this error and can't find the way to resolve.

Comment: Your code trial ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you used commons-compress jar in classpath?try this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18